# Datatable: Visible option doesn't work when Ajax call to render data

Tags: datatables

I have a table is using datatable and Ajax to get data on load.

```
const oTable = $('#product').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/ajax/admin/getproductlist/ajax.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "responsive": true,
    "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [-1],
                    "searchable": false,
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [1, 9, -2],
                    "width": "5%",
                },
                {
                    "targets": [1, -1],
                    "width": "10%",
                },
                {
                    "targets": [0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                    "width": "15%",
                },
                {
                    "targets": [3, 4],
                    "width": "30%",
                    "orderable": false,  << This worked
                    "visible": false    << DOESN't work
                }
            ],
    "columns"   : [
        { "data": "sku" },
        { "data": "master" },
        { "data": "thumbs", "orderable": false },       << This worked
        { "data": "name", "orderable": false },         << This worked
        { "data": "name_fr", "visible" : false },       << DOESN't work
        { "data": "product_tags", "orderable": false }, << This worked
        { "data": "brand_tags", "orderable": false },   << This worked
        { "data": "label_tags", "orderable": false },   << This worked
        { "data": "mer_tags", "orderable": false },     << This worked
        { "data": "status", "orderable": false },       << This worked
        { "data": "quantity_in_stock" },
    ],
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $('#dataTables-list-Product_filter input').unbind();
        $('#dataTables-list-Product_filter input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                oTable.search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });
        $('#dataTables-list-Product_filter input').bind('change', function(e) {
            oTable.search(this.value).draw();
        });
    },
});
```

I want to hide the columns when table finishes loading.

- Let's take an example for `name_fr`. I tried to add `visible: false` to config option but somehow this column always shows up again after page stop loading. The `orderable: false` works fine.
- I did add break point to debug the process. When table initialized, this column was hidden but after that something called it showing up again.
- The column was only hidden when I click on checkbox that I make a function to show/hide.

```
$('input[id^="toggle_vis_"]').on('click', function(e) {
   var column = oTable.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
   $(this).val() == 1 ? column.visible(false) : column.visible(true);
});
```

- So, I tried to but this to ready() function to hide column when page loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var column = oTable.column(4);
    column.visible(false);
});
```

And...it didn't work as well. :(

Would you please give me an idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: My simplified version of your DataTable works as expected - I was not able to recreate your problem. By "simplified" I mean that I removed the `ajax` call and the `serverSide` option. I used some hard-coded JSON source data. Can you provide a similar simplified [mre], which does demonstrate the problem?

Comment: It may also be worth double-checking the [conflict resolution](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs#Conflict-resolution) rules - but I don't think they explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Also, a side note: `sortable` is not a valid option in DataTables columns (or columndefs). The correct value is `orderable` (or the deprecated value `bSortable`). But `sortable` will be ignored, since it is unknown.

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames. I didn't know about the "simplified" term. I guessed that calling ajax might caused the problem so that's why I mentioned it on my example code. Posting question in here was too hard, last time I posted another question that I was warning because using non-allowed tags >"< I have no idea.

Comment: `sortable` I was wrong, that term was typed by me. Actually, I used `orderable` in my code. I fixed on question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @andrewjames to help me find out my problem.

There was a conflict between `orderable: false` and `responsive: true`.
The option `responsive: true` brought back my columns when finishing loading.

Solution: Remove or edit `responsive` to `false`

```
var oTable = $('#Product').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/ajax/admin/getproductlist/ajax.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    ...
    ...

    "responsive": false,
    ...
    ...
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: I am glad you resolved it - but having `responsive` set to true or false (or completely removed) makes no difference, in my version of your code: It works correctly either way.

Comment: Really? After read your comment, I set true to `responsive` and my problem happened again. When remove it, it worked as expected. I have no idea.

Comment: The only way to be sure would be to see a [mre] which shows the problem in a reliable, repeatable way. Currently I cannot find a way to cause this problem from happening at all.